# How to check if xml tag value is none in python

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I am trying to compare data of two api's responses. One of them returns xml. The issue is one of the tag in xml response is null. I can't find the way to check if the value exist or not.

Here is xml response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FCDB_RES_ENV>
    <FCDB_HEADER>
        <SOURCE>FCAT</SOURCE>
        <FCDBCOMP>FCDB</FCDBCOMP>
        <MSGID>MB_31051021591539014</MSGID>
        <CORRELID>MB_31051021591539014</CORRELID>
        <USERID>615</USERID>
        <BRANCH>000</BRANCH>
        <MODULEID>LGN</MODULEID>
        <SERVICE>GetEmailMobNoDetails</SERVICE>
        <OPERATION>GetEmailMobNoDetails</OPERATION>
        <SOURCE_USERID>FCAT</SOURCE_USERID>
        <DESTINATION>FCDB</DESTINATION>
        <COUNTRYCODE>T001</COUNTRYCODE>
        <USERTYPE>ENS</USERTYPE>
        <LANGID>eng</LANGID>
        <CHANNELID>01</CHANNELID>
    </FCDB_HEADER>
    <FCDB_BODY>
        <EMAILID/>
        <MOBNO>03006846625</MOBNO>
        <FCDB_ERROR_RESP>
            <ERROR>
                <ECODE>00</ECODE>
                <EDESC>Your transaction has been processed successfully.</EDESC>
            </ERROR>
        </FCDB_ERROR_RESP>
        <FCDB_WARNING_RESP>
            <WARNING>
                <WCODE/>
                <WDESC/>
            </WARNING>
        </FCDB_WARNING_RESP>
    </FCDB_BODY>
</FCDB_RES_ENV>
```

Please note the  return None value.

Here is the code which need to modify. Thanks in advance.

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload.format(cust_no, cust_type), headers=headers)

tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring(response2.text))
root = tree.getroot()

for l in root.findall("./FCDB_BODY/EMAILID"):
    if l is not None:
        xml_email = l.text
        print("XML Email is", xml_email)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Your "XML response" is not XML (or you pasted it only partly). In any case the XML is invalid.

Comment: @Tomalak I pasted partly. Let me edit and write valid xml

Comment: Ah, that's better. However the `<EMAILID>` element is empty in this XML, of course the `.text` is `None`. What do you get when you try `./FCDB_BODY/MOBNO` instead?

Comment: I get the value which in this case is "03006846625". I want to check before getting <EMAILID> value if it is empty or not. How should i do it? i can't find a way to insert if else here

Comment: `emailid = root.find("./FCDB_BODY/EMAILID")` (not `.findall()` - you only expect one hit anyway) and then: `if emailid is None or emailid.text is None or emailid.text == "": ... else: ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the lxml package? Because with

```
from lxml.etree import ElementTree, fromstring
data = """..."""  # your XML string here 
tree = ElementTree(fromstring(data))
```

I see you have a syntax error.

Moreover, do you want to retrieve the text of < EMAILID />? Because here it has no text at all.

First edit:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

data = """..."""  # Your XML string
tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring(data))
root = tree.getroot()

for l in root.findall("./FCDB_BODY/EMAILID"):
    if l is not None:
        xml_email = l.text
        if xml_email:
            print("XML Email is", xml_email)
        else:
            print("There is no email for this entry")
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: sorry i am using xml.etree. 
Also i do want to retrieve the text of < EMAILID /> but since i am performing many requests, some time the tag is empty. So i want to add any condition here to check if there is value or not